# How does content get propagated within multi instance Azure Websites

Tags: azure

I have a WordPress site that I am deploying to Azure Websites. Curious if I use multiple instances, what happens when a user uploads content?  Does the content get propagated automatically? I am not able to find anything in the Azure documentation regarding it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually Azure Websites uses a single shared location for content so updates will be reflected on all instances since they are uploaded into the same location.

Comment: And check out Nir's [Channel9 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-Internals-with-Nir-Mashkowski) on Web Sites internals. Tons of good low-level info there regarding deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Any updates made to the Azure Web Site HD should be considered temporary. At BUILD last year it was stated that each instance will get a copy of the “original” blob storage so any updates to one will not be propagated to the others. Of course, most of the internal workings of Azure are not published so this may have changed since then.  There is a nice WordPress plugin that will store uploaded media to your Windows Azure Blog Storage account http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/windows-azure-storage/  the user manual can be found here:  http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/windows-azure-storage/trunk/UserGuide.pdf